# Working with multiple dialog boxes, logics error

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, php-5.3

I am using the following code to View Complete Messages from Users, on my web page.
u can see my web page here : http://team-kh.hireexpertprogrammers.com/~maiarn/Admin.php
But the only prob is some logic Error here, When i randomly click on the View Complete link, the dialog Box, shows me the title and content of the first message. How can i avoid this error: 
Such that, which View Complete Link is clicked, the dialog box shall show the title and content of that row , message.

```
   <?php
   $i=0;
   while ($i < $num) {

   $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"FullName");
   $Name = $ f1;
   $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"EmailAddr");
   $string=mysql_result($result,$i,"Message");
   $limit=10;
   $string1 = myTruncate($string,$limit);

   ?>
   <tr>
   <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
   <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
   <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $string1; ?></font>

   <a id="button1"href="#">View Complete</a>
    <div id="dialog1"title="<?php echo $Name; ?>" style="display: none;">
   <?php echo $string; ?></div>
    </td>

    </tr>

    <?php
    $i++;
     }
     ?>
```

The script is

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js">
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("a#button1").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog1").dialog({height: 300, width: 500, modal: true});

    });

     });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to assign dynamic ID's to your dialogs based on a number or some other distinguishing string or load the information from the row into a single dialog before you display it (which would be preferable).

Comment: Ok, Thanks, But how to do it, I m very new to php, so wud u please provide sum code on how to load information from a row to single dialog box. Thanks